# How to create hash of structs keyed with Integer?

Tags: ruby, hash, struct

Excuse me my lame question, but I'm stuck with this.

I need to create hash of structs with default constructor.
I've tried with following code :

```
@@str = Struct.new("A", :x, :y)
@data = Hash.new { |v,k| v[k] = @@str.new('1','2') }
```

but it is not working. How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Struct.new("A", :x, :y)
@data = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = Struct::A.new('1','2') }
```